# Change meta viewport tag if android or iphone

Tags: android, iphone, user-agent, viewport

I want to change the meta viewport tag based on detection of an android or an iphone. I have this code but it is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
var i;
var ua = navigator.userAgent;

var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) !=null;
var isAndroid = /Android/i.test(ua);

var isiPhone = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) !=null;
var isiPhone = /iPhone/i.test(ua);

if(isiPhone) {
for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) {
  if (metas[i].name == "viewport") {
    metas[i].content = "";
  }
}
} else if(isAndroid) {
for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) {
  if (metas[i].name == "viewport") {
    metas[i].content = "";
  }
}
} else {
for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) {
  if (metas[i].name == "viewport") {
    metas[i].content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=.5";
  }
}
}
</script>
```

I tried this code as a test and it works just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var isiPad = /iPad/i.test(ua) || /iPhone OS 4_3_3/i.test(ua) || /iPhone OS 4_3_3/i.test(ua);

var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) !=null;
var isAndroid = /Android/i.test(ua);

var isiPhone = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) !=null;
var isiPhone = /iPhone/i.test(ua);

if(isiPad) {
alert("hello ipad!");
} else if(isAndroid) {
alert("hello android!");
} else if(isiPhone) {
alert("hello iphone!");
}
</script>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong with the meta tag code?

Answer (score 1):

target meta viewport and test the user agent :

```
 viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");

 var iOS_iphone = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone)/i) ? true : false );

    if (iOS_iphone==true){
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.2, maximum-scale=0.2, user-scalable=no');
        }

    if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){ 
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to allow user scaling on iPad only. It is not dependent on jQuery and so can be placed in the head, after the viewport meta and before any other external scripts for perf reasons.

```
<!-- Allow zooming for iPad only -->
<script>
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
        var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width; initial-scale=1; user-scalable=1;');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the open source [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) php script. Here is all it took once I downloaded the lightweight script:

```
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if ($detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet())
    echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />';
```